Error Ngspice on google colab: there aren't any circuits loaded
I'm trying to simulate a diode circuit on Google Colab but it gives an error when I try to simulate the circuit with a diode. I get an Error:there aren't any circuits loaded
First, I install conda environment
!pip install condacolab
import condacolab
condacolab.install()

Then, install pyspice and ngspice
!pip install pyspice
!mamba install -c conda-forge ngspice

Then, I copied the example code from the pyspice site
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


import PySpice.Logging.Logging as Logging
logger = Logging.setup_logging()


from PySpice.Doc.ExampleTools import find_libraries
from PySpice.Spice.Netlist import Circuit
from PySpice.Spice.Library import SpiceLibrary
from PySpice.Unit import *
from PySpice.Physics.SemiConductor import ShockleyDiode


libraries_path = find_libraries()
spice_library = SpiceLibrary(libraries_path)

After this part, I get this on my terminal:
2024-06-06 01:16:49,883 - PySpice.Doc.ExampleTools.find_libraries - INFO - SPICE library path is /usr/local/lib/python3.10/libraries
The next part, no error occurs
circuit = Circuit('Diode Characteristic Curve')

#circuit.include(spice_library['1N4148'])
circuit.model('1N4148','D1',
              IS = 4.352E-9,N=1.906,BV = 110,
              IBV = 0.0001, RS = 0.6458, CJO = 7.048E-13,
              VJ = 0.869 , M = 0.03, FC = 0.5 , TT = 3.48E-9)
circuit.V('input', 'n_in', circuit.gnd, 10@u_V)
circuit.R(1, 'n_in', 'n_out', 1@u_Ω) # not required for simulation
circuit.X('D1', '1N4148', 'n_out', circuit.gnd)
print(circuit)

Then, on the simulation part I got an Error:there aren't any circuits loaded
# Fixme: Xyce ???
temperatures = [0, 25, 100]@u_Degree
analyses = {}
for temperature in temperatures:
    simulator = circuit.simulator(temperature=temperature, nominal_temperature=temperature)
    analysis = simulator.dc(Vinput=slice(-2, 5, .01))
    analyses[float(temperature)] = analysis

I got this on the terminal:
2024-06-06 01:17:21,909 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared._send_char - ERROR - Error: unknown subckt: xd1 n_out 0 1n4148
2024-06-06 01:17:21,911 - PySpice.Spice.NgSpice.Shared.NgSpiceShared._send_char - ERROR - Error: there aren't any circuits loaded.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NgSpiceCommandError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-1145e39177f7> in <cell line: 4>()
      4 for temperature in temperatures:
      5     simulator = circuit.simulator(temperature=temperature, nominal_temperature=temperature)
----> 6     analysis = simulator.dc(Vinput=slice(-2, 5, .01))
      7     analyses[float(temperature)] = analysis

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySpice/Spice/NgSpice/Shared.py in exec_command(self, command, join_lines)
    849 
    850         if self._error_in_stdout or self._error_in_stderr:
--> 851             raise NgSpiceCommandError("Command '{}' failed".format(command))
    852 
    853         if join_lines:

NgSpiceCommandError: Command 'run' failed

Please help, I'm really lost here. Thank you
